# Mvvmcross Windowd Phone

Tags: c#, windows, mvvmcross

I have WP application with mvvmcross 
And I have in the view mediaelement control that his name is media_play
And I want to use him in the core, so I need to send him from the view to the viewmoudle as dynamic 
How I do that ? 
I need to do that when the view created so I can edit the control from the vieemoudle and use the controls funcs

Comment: This control is platform specific. The core is generic, so you can't/shouldn't have any reference to it in the core. What do you want to do? Can you give any code example?

Comment: Try searching for things like http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Mvvm+MediaElement - you'll find lots of questions and answers about binding media operations to a ViewModel. Also read up on messenger, on interfaces, on plugins - if you read lots, and experiment a bit, then I think you should be able to find a style you like

Comment: I knot that the core is generic but I can use dynamic object like I write in the post...